# Docker-local volume mount to the container:Connection refused

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am quite new to the world of docker and I am trying to set this up:

Running a solarwinds whd container and trying to mount a local volume on the host using this command:

```
docker run -d -p 8081:8081 --name=whdinstance -v pwd:/usr/local/webhelpdesk/bin/pgsql/var/lib/pgsql/9.2/data solarwinds/whd-embedded:latest
```

This starts the container and the volume is mounted but as soon as I go to ***localhost:8081*** to login to the web helpdesk portal it asks me to select the database and then says "***Connection refused***" [See Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVek1.png)

can someone please help, if this might be an issue with the way I am mounting the volume?

Answer (score 0):

Here exemples of how using volumes:

For use directory volume

```
docker run -itd -p 80:80 --name wordpress -v /path/in/your/host :/path/in/your/container wordpress
```

You have to put you `-v` and then the path of your directory in your container `:` the path of your shared directory on your host. When you done this you can choose your image !

So for you it should be something like

```
docker run -itd -p 8081:8081 --name=whdinstance -v /usr/local/webhelpdesk/bin/pgsql/var/lib/pgsql/9.2/data solarwinds/whd-embedded:latest
```

Comment: Hello @thibault, thank you for the response. I tried it the way you suggested, it mounts the container directory but I don't know where on the local host is the volume directory. If I open Kitematic and check the volume tab, it shows the docker directory and the local directory is still empty. And i think as per dockers documentation it should be "-v /path/in/host/:/path/in/container". And i am still getting the connection refused error.

Comment: You're right for `"-v /path/in/host/:/path/in/container"`, I edited my message. Your volumes are in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/`.
And for your DB problem I think it's because you didn't link any DB to your container, you can use `--link` or just `-p <ip_of_db>:<access_port>:<db_port>` when you create your DB and link your application to it, in your app config files.